# Material UI - Select Menu with End Adornment

Tags: material-ui, react-select

Is it possible to get an endAdornment into a Select menu in MaterialUI?

I want to add content to the right hand side of the down pointer on the select menu.

```js
endAdornment={
   <InputAdornment position="end">
        <Insights />
   </InputAdornment>

<Select
   labelId="demo-mutiple-name-label"
   id="demo-mutiple-name"
   multiple
   value={fieldName}
   onChange={handleChange}
   input={<Input id="select-multiple-chip" />}
   renderValue={(selected) => (
     <div className={classes.chips}>
     {selected.map((value) => (
        <Chip key={value} label={value} className={classes.chip} />
        ))}
     </div>
     )}
     MenuProps={MenuProps}
   >
   {field.map((field) => (
    <MenuItem key={field} value={field} >
        {field}
    </MenuItem>
   ))}
                            
</Select>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I took Javier answer but did the styling a bit different. As he mentions, Material UI `Select` Component supports `endAdornment`, but, it doesn't work quite well with the `Select` arrow. The main problem is that whatever you put there, it will overlap it.
Here's an example of how I did it.

First, define a class that you will apply to the `InputAdornment` element. You simply need to give it a bit of right padding so that it doesn't render on top of the arrow:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    selectAdornment: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(3),
    },
  })
);
```

Then just add the class to the `InputAdornment` in your `Select`

```html
<FormControl className={classes.rowInputRoot} error={!!error}>
  <Select
    labelId="id"
    value={selectValue}
    endAdornment={
      <InputAdornment className={classes.selectAdornment} position="end">
        <CircularProgress size={20} />
      </InputAdornment>
    }
  >
    <MenuItem value="" selected>
      <em>Select</em>
    </MenuItem>
    {rowData.listValues?.map((value, i) => {
      return <MenuItem value={value[idPropName]}>{value.label}</MenuItem>;
    })}
  </Select>
</FormControl>;
```

This will render the adornment with a bit of margin right to avoid overlapping with the Select arrow.

Comment: Instead of overlap. mine was getting overridden. so in html page my icon is nowhere to be found to shift its position.

Comment: How are you adding the addorment to your Select? can you paste your code here so that I can take a look and help? If you tried with the example I posted above it should not get overriden,

Comment: I dont think this is a good solution, because now I cannot click on the dropdown to bring down the list.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `<Select>`, we could use `<TextField>` with `<MenuItem>` in it.

```js
<TextField
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
      name="cls"
      select
      label="Items"
      helperText="Please select Class"
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">something</InputAdornment>
        )
      }}
    >
      <MenuItem>Item 1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Item 2</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Item 3</MenuItem>
    </TextField>
  );
```

See the sample sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-9vqb3?file=/demo.js

Comment: This was super helpful. For whatever reason, I kept using `endAdornment: {}` instead of `endAdornment: ()`... and making that change fixed my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Current Material Ui Select Component supports endAdornment, but, it doesn't work quite well with the select arrow.

What I did was to add an startAdornment and added a makeStyles class to put the adornment in a absolute position,  the makeStyle class has the following content:

```js
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      selectAdornment: {
        "& .MuiButtonBase-root": {
          position: "absolute",
          padding: 0,
          right: "32px",
          top: "calc(50% - 12px)",
        },
      },
    }));
```

Select look like this:

```js
    <Select
      {...props}
      onChange={handleChange}
      startAdornment={
        <InputAdornment position="start" className={classes.selectAdornment}>
          <IconButton>
            <Tooltip title="tooltip text">
              <HelpIcon
                color="primary"
              />
            </Tooltip>
          </IconButton>
        </InputAdornment>
      }
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Like other answers on this thread, the Material UI Select Component supports endAdornment and startAdornment but, like others have mentioned the select arrow will overlap with it.

My solution to this was actually overriding the position of the select arrow.

```js
    <Select
     labelId="id"
     value={selectValue}
     endAdornment={
      <IconButton>
        <Tooltip title="tooltip text">
          <HelpIcon
          color="primary"
         />
        </Tooltip>
      </IconButton>
    }
    />
```

then, wherever you have your css, include:

```css
    .MuiSelect-icon { right: 40px !important; }
```

but it is entirely dependent on where you want your select arrow, so play around with the values depending on where you want the select arrow.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has said, Select doesn't support endAdornment very well. I found the best way around it to be using absolute positioning. This is very similar to javier's response, but it's important to set pointer events to "none", so that the adornment won't prevent the user from interacting with the dropdown arrow. Here is my solution with inline styles:

```
 <Select
    value={value}
    label="Label"
    endAdornment={
        <InputAdornment 
          position="end" 
          sx={{ pointerEvents: "none", position: "absolute", right: 35 }}>
            adornment
        </InputAdornment>
    }
  >
    <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

If your elements overlap, adjust the width of the Select.

Comment: The added benefit of absolute positioning is that the dropdown button is still clickable in the adornment area. Without absolute, the cursor becomes a text cursor and clicking doesn't open the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```js
<FormControl>
    <Select {...props}>
        {values.map((value) => (
            <MenuItem
                key={value}
                value={value}
            >
                <Typography variant="inherit">{value}</Typography>
                <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                    <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
                        <Check />
                    </IconButton>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </MenuItem>
        ))}
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
            <Select
                onChange={onChange}
                endAdornment={
                    xVisible ? (
                        <div
                            onClick={xClick}
                        >
                            <i className="bi bi-x-lg"></i>
                        </div>
                    ) : null
                }
                sx={{
                    "& .MuiSelect-iconOutlined": {
                        display: xVisible ? "none" : "",
                    },
                    "&.Mui-focused .MuiIconButton-root": {
                        color: "primary.main",
                    },
                }}
            >
                <MenuItem value="10">Ten</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="20">Twenty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
```

Answer (score -3):

For anyone else trying to do this - I haven't figured out how to do it, but a work around that may be good enough is to put all the content that you want in the endAdornment in a right aligned FormHelper - so that it appears below the input box in the form field.